# Icon in bootstrap not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've followed a tutorial about CodeIgniter and I have a problem in putting icon from a bootstrap class. Here is the code

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                <! -- Main Column -->
                    <div class="span9">
                        <section>
                            <h2>Page name </h2>
                        </section>
                    </div>

                    <! -- Side Bar -->
                    <div class="span3">
                        <section>
                            <?php echo mailto('iamjohnx3302@gmail.com', '<i class="icon-user"</i> iamjohnx3302@gmail.com'); ?> <br>
                            <?php echo anchor('admin/user/logout', '<i class="icon-off"></i>logout'); ?>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
```

Also, I have added the bootstrap script and CSS by :

```
<head>
    <title><?php echo $meta_title; ?></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
```

Also below the body, I added the script :

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: <div class="span3">
                        <section>
                            <?php echo mailto('iamjohnx3302@gmail.com', '<i class="icon-user"</i> iamjohnx3302@gmail.com'); ?> <br>
                            <?php echo anchor('admin/user/logout', '<i class="icon-off"></i>logout'); ?>
                        </section>
                    </div>

Comment: this is font awesome or glyp?

Comment: Don't you mean 'gylphicon'? This syntax reminds me of materialize icons. If I'm not mistaken, bootstrap's icons are called gylphicons. http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: if you want to use, `glyphicon` your code like this `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>` but `<i></i>` is fontawesome i think.

Comment: yes thats it. it doesn't work ..

Comment: I believe Glyphicons require the fonts folder of bootstrap to work, are you including them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use Glyphicons use this one `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>` and you can find details here http://getbootstrap.com/components/ or if you want to use Font-Awesome you can use like this `<i class="fa fa-bluetooth-b"></i>` details here https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

Comment: check your file, if you include your files correctly, you can see on console.

Answer (score 0):

The icon from Bootstrap,

you should follow the class name like this:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
```

For your reference [Bootstrap Components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons)

Hope this helps.